# No comments on static front page

Tags: posts, comments

I have had this problem before. I want my homepage to be very simple, and I don't want it to be a discussion forum or a place where you can leave your comments.

I wrote yesterday and got some good answers. However, I had to change the theme, because what I wanted to do, wasn't possible with the theme Alexandria. I have made a very simple front page, but when I want to erase the comment area from my page 2, it's just not possible. I have chosen a static page, I have unchecked all the markings in discussion. But nothing helps.

Underneath the comments area there is a lot of writing about the HTML and what attributes and codes are legal. I would love to be able to remove it all. What can I do to remove it all?

Comment: There are two places where you can turn them off, the general place and per page. -> Uncheck the Comments checkbox in Screen Options in Pages should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be do difficult to achieve. What I would suggest is to create yourself a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). It is quick and very easy. The reason for this is, **never** make changes to a theme/plugin that you are not the author of.

Once you have your child theme up and running, copy the page.php template from the parent theme to your child theme and rename it front-page.php (as I suggested in your previous question, go and read about [creating a static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page))

Open front-page.php and delete everything comment related. This should be at the bottom of your template. Save this template.

This should be enough